# File getting blank during write operation node js

Tags: node.js

I have found this issue in following two situations.

1. When there is lots of free space on the server.
2. When there is no space available on the server.

I am reading particular JSON file using following:

```
fs.readFileSync(_file_path, 'utf-8');
```

and after some manipulation on the received data, I am writing the updated data to the same file using following:

```
fs.writeFileSync(_file_path, {stringified-json});
```

During this operation my file is becoming empty sometime, now I am trying to reproduce this issue locally but not able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs.writeFileSync()` will throw if there was an error, so make sure you have the code in a `try`/`catch` block and that your `catch` is not simply swallowing the error. (For example, an empty `catch` block will cause the exception to be swallowed or, in other words, ignored.)

If this is a script or some other process that might get invoked multiple times simultaneously (e.g., multiple processes or you're using workers), then you need to use file locking or some other mechanism to make sure you don't have a race condition. If process A opens the file for writing (thus emptying it) and then process B opens the file for reading before process A is finished with the file, that could result in an empty file if process B reads the empty file and the code is written such that it will write an empty file as a result.

Without more information (e.g., error logs), any answer is likely to be pure guess work. But those are two things I'd check.

Comment: If it throws, should it not halt the whole process...?

Comment: You're right. I've edited the answer to specify that this will only be the case if there is already a try/catch block and it swallows the error. I've also added a second possibility (race condition between workers or multiple processes). Without more information, any answer is going to be largely guess work, I think.

Comment: Trott, I am using try catch error, but the second possibility chances are there but I am sure I am not emptying file, still I will check for it. Thanks.